# how to delete bulk woocommerce products associated with a category

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I'm trying to delete a large amount of products in Wocommerce from one category. I have tried few WordPress plugins which didn't work successfully.

Is there a plugin that can delete all products from certain category?

I am also trying to make an SQL Query to delete all products under a particular category but that's not working as well.

Answer (score 0):

I also found a plugin that can solve the problem above; (woocommerce store toolkit), it kind of deletes in batches of 100s for any specified field/attribute)
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-store-toolkit/